# Position a Container in the middle of screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using flutter. I made a reusable Container widget and used it in the column widget. I want to center the container in the middle of the screen. The Container currently is showing at the top of the screen. The code is attached below. I am glad if someone helps. ..

```dart
Widget mainOptionsWidget(
  BuildContext context,
  String title,
  IconData icon,
  String cardId,
) {
  return Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
      minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
    ),
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(60),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
      ),
    ),
    // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 60,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And used

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        mainOptionsWidget(
          context,
          "I WANT",
          Icons.cached_outlined,
          "1",
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: What are you using as parent widget, Can you provide full widget that will reproduce the same issue such as scaffold body. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            mainOptionsWidget(
              context,
              "I WANT",
              Icons.cached_outlined,
              "1",
            ),
            
             ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Center` widget on body.

```dart
body: Center(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        mainOptionsWidget(
          context,
          "I WANT",
          Icons.cached_outlined,
          "1",
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: welcome, You can check more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)